# Loading knockout.js form in div from AJAX call

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I'm attempting to load some HTML stored as text for a knockout.js form. A customer's server will use an AJAX GET call to my server which will then return the HTML for the table. Right now, the table is being returned, however it's formatted like knockout.js hasn't been loaded but I'm not receiving any errors (dropdown not populated, foreach loop for a table is displaying a blank row, a secondary div is displayed when it should only be displayed once a submit button has been pressed).

When I have the HTML on this page it works, so I'm pretty sure it's not incorrect code in the form. The only thing I can think of is that knockout is picky about single and double quotes, although I feel like that would rsult in errors. Right now I'm testing on my server so same origin policy shouldn't be an issue at the moment.

Here is the page that initially loads

```
//main.html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>

<!-- I also tried to include the knockout file includes here but made no difference -->

<script>
<!-- call to get HTML for knockout form -->
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/orders/return_form',
        data: "true",
        success: function(response) { // on success..
            $('#order_div').html(response); // update the DIV
        }
    })
</script>

<div id = "order_div">
        <!-- returned knockout form goes here -->
</div>


<script src="knockout.js"></script>
<script src="knockout_info.js"></script>  <!-- MVVM file -->
<script src = "Knockout-Validation/Src/knockout.validation"</script>
```

Here is the code to return the code for the table

```
//orders/return_form

if($_GET['true']){

     echo "table code here ";  
     //I tried to encode this before but got all kinds of extra markup due to whitespace and other misc. characters

    //or

    $form = new stdClass;
    $form->table = "<form method='post'>
                    <input type='textbox' name='text'/>
                    <input type='submit' name='textsubmit'/>
                </form>";
    echo $form->table;


}
```

If I include the table instead of calling for the code it works. However, it's a pretty lengthy form and considering this code will be on someone else's server calling to mine, I'd like to keep their code to a minimum.

Comment: I've deleted my answer. You'll have to provide more info so we can find the cause. What is the content of `/orders/return_form` and `knockout_info.js`?

Comment: Try calling the ko.applyBindings(vm) after you set the div's html.

Comment: @Stijn I re-arranged a few things and re-binded as you suggested and got it to work. If you post that answer again I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing any binding.

```
success: function(response) { // on success..
    $('#order_div').html(response); // update the DIV
    ko.applyBindings(myModel); // rebind
}
```

Comment: That's part of the MVVM which is knockout_info.js. That file is included and shows up in my network tab. Where are you suggesting this goes? It certainly doesn't go on my HTML page (maint.html).

Comment: In `success` you set the html from your AJAX call, but you're not doing any binding there, so nothing will happen. Knockout binds when you tell it to.

Comment: See the edit to my answer. I think you're misunderstanding how binding works. Binding is on-demand, Knockout does not watch your DOM to see when new potential binding targets are added to the page, you have to give it a nudge.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, thanks. Why would the form work when it's on the page but not when it's returned from the call? There is absolutely nothing changed except for where the code is coming from.

Comment: Because when you include the form on the page, it's already present before your `knockout_info.js` file executes (and binds). When you do it via AJAX, `knockout_info.js` could be executing before the AJAX call completes and adds the form to your page.

Comment: I tried to do this but it's saying "unable to parse bindings: contents undefined" in reference to one of the DIV's that I have in my form. As I previously stated, when I just copy/paste the entire form it works.